# Two Different Statements about Schur's Decomposition Theorem (Linear Algebra)

Tags: linear-algebra

My book: *Linear Algebra Done Right* 3rd Edition by *Sheldon Axler* states the Schur's Theorem as follows.

> **Schur's Theorem.** Suppose $V$ is a finite-dimensional complex vector space and $T$ is a linear operator on $V$. Then $T$ has an upper-triangular matrix with respect to some orthonormal basis of $V$.

In other words, for any $n \times n$ complex-valued matrix, there is an orthonormal basis in which that matrix is upper-triangular.

But many other textbooks state the Schur's Decomposition as follows.

> **Schur's Deocmposition Theorem.** Suppose $V$ is a finite-dimensional complex vector space and $T$ is a linear operator on $V$. Let $B$ be a basis of $V$. Then there exist an unitary matrix $U$ such that $$ \mathcal{M}(T,B) = U^\ast A U$$
>   where $A$ is an upper triangular matrix.

Here, $\mathcal{M}(T)$ denote matrix representation of $T$ respect to basis $B$. 
What is the relationship between those two? Are they equivalent? If yes, how can I prove it?

Comment: The orthonormal basis in the first version of the theorem consists of the columns of $U^*$ in the second theorem. The $A$ in the second theorem is the upper-triangular matrix with respect to that basis.

Comment: @angryavian So you mean that $B$ is considered as standard basis?

Comment: Yes, sorry, that's what I meant.

Comment: @xbh Oh.. so we can not freely choose basis $B$, rather it is determined by the theorem. Right? Many examples in the Internet starts from matrix, not from operator, so I was confused.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I read the statement wrong. Ignore me.

Comment: Given any basis $B$, we can change the basis to an orthonormal one $E$ s.t. $\mathcal M(T, E) = A$ is upper triangular, and the transitional matrix from $B$ to $E$ is given by an unitary matrix $U$.

Comment: @xbh Yes that's where I'm stuck. Is there a way to prove that such transition matrix (from $B$ to $E$) is unitary matrix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Proof of the equivalency

$(2) \implies (1)$

Let $\mathcal E' = \mathcal B U^*$, then $T (\mathcal B) = \mathcal B U^* A U $, or $T (\mathcal E' U) = \mathcal E' U U^* A U = \mathcal E' A U $, hence $T (\mathcal E') = \mathcal E' A$, i.e. $\mathcal M(T, \mathcal E') = A$ is upper triangular. Now apply Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization process to $\mathcal E'$ to obtain an orthonormal basis $\mathcal E$, then $\mathcal M(T, \mathcal E)$ is still upper triangular, hence the statement.

$(1) \implies (2)$

From now on, the bold-italic letters represent matrices, the regular letters are mappings, and the calligraphic letters are basis. Also $\mathbb C^n \cong \mathrm M_{n,1}(\mathbb C)$ is the collection of $n \times 1$ complex matrices.

Let $\boldsymbol S = \mathcal M(T, \mathcal B)$, on $W = \mathbb C^n$, define linear operator $S \colon  \boldsymbol x \mapsto \boldsymbol {Sx}$ where $\boldsymbol x \in \mathbb C^n$, then apply $(1)$ to the operator $S$, there exists some ONB $\mathcal F$ of $\mathbb C^n$ that $\mathcal M(S, \mathcal F) = \boldsymbol A$ is upper triangular. Let $\mathcal E$ be the standard basis of $\mathbb C^n$, and let $\mathcal F = \mathcal E \boldsymbol U$, then $\boldsymbol U$ is unitary. Write $\boldsymbol U^*$ instead of $\boldsymbol U$, i.e. $\mathcal F = \mathcal E \boldsymbol U^*$ and $S(\mathcal F) = \mathcal F \boldsymbol A$ becomes $S (\mathcal E \boldsymbol U^*) = \mathcal E \boldsymbol U^* \boldsymbol A$, hence $S (\mathcal E) = \mathcal E (\boldsymbol U^*\boldsymbol {AU})$. But $S (\mathcal E) = \boldsymbol S$, hence $\boldsymbol S = \boldsymbol {U}^* \boldsymbol {AU}$. Hence the statement.